# Seeing quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can someone explain simply what a quotient group is?

I've read a lot of convoluted and unnecessarily tough descriptions on it but it seems like a really simple idea.

**Question**
Show that $$8 \mathbb{Z} / 56 \mathbb{Z} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_7$$

I'm sure this is a really easy question if I can just realize what a quotient group is. If you got an easy way to describe isomorphism, that would be great too!

Answer (score 2):

Quotienting anything simply means that you are dividing it. For dividing a set most of the times one uses an equivalence relation on it which gives a partition into disjoint sets which is easy to handle. Similarly in group theory given a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ of $G$ a natural question arises as to how do elements in $gH=\{gh|h\in H, g\in G\}$ look like. Carrying on the same idea of equivalence classes we define a relation on $G$ as $g_1\sim g_2$ iff $g_1{g_2}^{-1}\in H$. It is easy to see that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation and the equivalence classes are precisely $G/H=\{gH|g\in G\}$. The reason to write it as $G/H$ is that we are "identifying" the elements of $H$ in $G$.

Since we are dealing with group theory so it is natural to ask that when is the set $G/H$ a group itself. It turns out that $G/H$ is a group iff $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Similarly isomorphism between two groups means that the groups are "essentially the same" with different faces,i.e., if certain group-theoretic property is same for one group then it must be true for all other groups isomorphic to it.

As for your question, I think wckronholm has already given an answer.

Comment: Is this really the simplest explanation to explain quotient groups? Can you show me a simple example perhaps?

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{2Z}$ under addition as group operation. Now using above equivalence relation we see that $[0]$ is the set of all even numbers and $[1]$ is the set of all odd numbers so there are exactly two elements $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$ which can be written as $\{0,1\}$. Now its easy to see that there is an isomorphism between this set and the group $\mathbb{Z_2}$ and hence $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$ is a group, infact a quotient group.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $G$ is abelian, as in your example. One way to think of $G/H$ is that two elements $g, h \in G$ are equivalent in $G/H$ if and only if $g-h \in H$. So in your example, $8$ and $64$ are equivalent in $8 \mathbb{Z}/56\mathbb{Z}$ because $8-64 = -56 \in 56 \mathbb{Z}$.

An isomorphism is a function $f \colon G_1 \to G_2$ which is a bijection and preserves the group operations.

Comment: The question asks if 8Z/56Z is an isomorphism to $Z_7$. I don't know how to read that from your answer. You talk about being "equivalent" in G/H but what does that mean and how does that relate to the question? Thank you.

Comment: I think your task is to show that $8 \mathbb{Z}/56\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_7$.

And my statement about equivalence can be taken as a definition.

Comment: Why do you say if and only if $g-h \in H$ ?

Comment: Think about $\mathbb{Z}_4 = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. In this group, $3=7$ because $3-7 \in 4\mathbb{Z}$. Similarly, $12 = -24$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4$ because $12-(-24) \in 4\mathbb{Z}$.