# Isomorphism problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Problem**

Show that $$4 \mathbb{Z} / 8 \mathbb{Z} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$$

Can someone explain what the quotient group consists of in the most simple terms as humanly possible (freshman maths major here) and then explain to me how I'd go about showing that it is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{Z}_2$

I'm having  some real problems understand this concept.

Comment: This question is not really substantially different from your question the other day. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716993/seeing-quotient-groups

Comment: Yes but I really needed more insight into it. I'm just trying to learn here.

Comment: Maybe the problem is you are not familiar enough with the concepts of equivalence relation and equivalence classes? These notions are key if you want to understand quotient groups.

Comment: There are many gaps in my understanding of abstract algebra/group theory. I partly blame the school for making us take this course in our first semester. Those of us who are taking the class and are in our first semester clearly do not have the mathematical maturity to understand these concepts as none of us understand the material. I'm even considering switching majors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$$4\Bbb Z=\{4m\;;\;m\in\Bbb Z\}\;,\;\;8\Bbb Z:=\{8m\;;\;m\in\Bbb Z\}$$

From the above it clearly follows $\;8\Bbb Z\le4\Bbb Z\;$. Now, define

$$\phi:4\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z_2\;,\;\;\phi(4m):=\begin{cases}0&,\;\;m\;\;\text{is even}\\{}\\1&,\;\;m\;\;\text{is odd}\end{cases}$$

Show the above is a homomorphism and apply the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: How does it clearly follow that $8 \mathbb{Z} \leq 4 \mathbb{Z} $ ? Thanks

Comment: @Paze, is every multiple of eight a multiple of four? :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for the time being that we are considering only postive entries in $4\mathbb{Z}$ then $4\mathbb{Z}=\{0,4,8,12,16,20,24,...\}$...Similarly $8\mathbb{Z}$ = $\{0,8,16,24,...\}$. The whole idea of quotienting a group by a subgroup is to identity the elemnts of the subgroup. So, for example in your problem you need to identify elements of $4\mathbb{Z}$ which are in $8\mathbb{Z}$...hence there are exactly two elements in $4\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$, those which belong to $*\mathbb{Z}$ (like $0,8,16,..$) and those which do not (like $4,12,20,...)$...now in order to show isomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$, follow the procedure described by DonAntonio.